# R lm log v log log for asymptotic fit

Tags: r, linear-models, power-function

I have data from a "bleed" experiment. That is, I fill a chamber with a gas that I can measure precisely (say, methane), and then just let it sit. The chamber has a natural bleed rate, which is obviously asymptotic with the concentration of the gas until it reaches equilibrium with the ambient concentration.

I have 5000 observations in subset_df\$ch4 and another column that is just the sequence numbers 1-5000 (subset_df\$seq). The black plot in the attached is CH4 x seq:

[image]

I create a log transformed version of the CH4 and sequence numbers:

```
subset_df$log_CH4 <- log(subset_df$CH4)
subset_df$log_seq = log(subset_df$seq)
```

Now, if I fit CH4 using:

```
model <- lm(log_CH4 ~ log_seq, data = subset_df)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
subset_df$pred <- predict(model, newdata = subset_df)                                                                                              
lines(exp(subset_df$pred), type='l', col='blue')
```

I get the very poor-looking blue fit with these coefficients:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)                                                                                                 
(Intercept)  9.6946053  0.0015909  6093.9   <2e-16 ***                                                                                             
log_seq     -0.0282991  0.0002101  -134.7   <2e-16 ***
```

But if I fit it using:

```
model <- lm(log_CH4 ~ seq, data = subset_df)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
subset_df$pred <- predict(model, newdata = subset_df)                                                                                              
lines(exp(subset_df$pred), type='l', col='red')
```

I get the very nice-looking red fit with these coefficients:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)                                                                                                 
(Intercept)  9.537e+00  4.648e-05  205207   <2e-16 ***                                                                                             
seq         -2.222e-05  1.627e-08   -1366   <2e-16 ***
```

Note that the only difference is that I'm not log transforming the indexes (seq) in the latter fit.

Several questions: 1: If the blue fit looks so bad, why are the fit statistics so good? 1.5: Why didn't it fit the "fast" part of the loglog curve to the data? 2: I can't seem to recreate the numbers that predict() is creating. That is, I want the equations, but no version of an equation using those coefs gives me the results of predict() that I'm seeing. (I could of course just dump predict()'s numbers, but I'm actually after the equations, not these particular numbers.)

I think I'm somehow faking myself out; maybe an lm on loglog or single log transformed data isn't the right thing to do here.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.